# Error importing tensorflow in simple python code with import

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow

I am trying to run sample code in tensor flow with only one line - import tensorflow as tf. But it gives this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "sample.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf   File "/home/djlimdiwala/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *   File "/home/djlimdiwala/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/djlimdiwala/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "/home/djlimdiwala/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()   File "/home/djlimdiwala/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description) ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory



Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace above this error message when asking for help.
```

CAN ANYONE HELP IN THIS?

Comment: Looks like you need to install the cuda drivers. Theres a very good set of instructions here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/ Try to get working first just using the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Focus on this part:
"ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

The reason why this message is displayed because Tensorflow couldn't find the place where the Nvidia cuda library is installed. Try to install it properly along with the tensorflow.

If you are using the pre-built TensorFlow binaries(included in their website https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux) then please check the supported cuda and cudnn versions before installing. Those pre-built TensorFlow versions support specific versions only.

Answer (score 0):

It is giving you this error because some how when you install cuda, it does not save its location in the environment.

```
ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Export the path to cuda lib:

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

> cuda_version: 8.0
>
> cuDNN_version: 5.1